# Why is there no "Freedom Caucus" in US Senate?

Tags: united-states, congress

US House of Representatives has "[Freedom Caucus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Caucus)" that has about 30 members who are cohesively more conservative and/or sympathize with Tea Party.

Today's 538 podcast mentioned tangentially a fact I wasn't explicitly noting before but that seems rather interesting: **there's no 6-7 member equivalent of Freedom Caucus in the US Senate** (the numbers are extrapolated linearly).

**Why is that?**

Comment: Because you have to appeal to fewer voters to get into the house v. senate.

Comment: The Senators supported by the [Senate Conservatives Fund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senate_Conservatives_Fund) are a good proxy for what a "Senate Freedom Caucus" would look like.

Answer (score 10):

Senators are voted in at the state level.

Representatives are voted in at the district level.

As such, senators have to appeal to a much wider audience than a lot of representatives do--especially representatives in heavily gerrymandered districts.

As such, representatives have the luxury of being further to the left or right than their counterparts in the senate given the often more specific voter demographic.

In addition, there are simply a lot more representatives than senators. That gives you a larger, more politically diverse pool of candidates to create a like-minded coalition within the ranks.

That doesn't explain *why* some of the *more* conservative Senators haven't formed their own coalition within the Senate, but does explain why the makeup of the house makes it more likely for it to happen there given they have room to have more polarized viewpoints and remain elected.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to remember that there are several differences between the House and the Senate

- House members are elected every 2 years. Senators are elected for 6.
- The House has 435 members while the Senate has 100 members
- The Senate tends to be a much more deliberate body (with the Filibuster that tends to require 60 votes on contentious issues). The House a more impetuous one (with a simple majority ruling all issues)

So members of the House do tend to form their own groups. In some ways, the House is [a bit more like a parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament), with different factions forming groups. In 2010, [Bart Stupak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bart_Stupak) and a small group of Democrats were able to hold up the bill that became Obamacare. Stupak wanted abortion restrictions and accepted President Obama's executive order, limiting abortion funding with Federal dollars. Stupak's group put the Democrats over the 216 threshold to make Obamacare law.

The Senate, however, has a smaller group to deal with and more power per person. A single Senator may, for instance, place a hold on a bill or nomination (as of last week, no nominations can now be held for cloture, only delayed). That hold requires a cloture vote to proceed, (which is where the filibuster comes into play). As such, blocking a law is a much simpler matter since filibusters tend to break down along party lines.